# How to write/output multiline Json in Java?

Tags: java, json, maven

I am right now using the json-simple library, and it appears that it is not possible to create a multiline json there. Could not find a definitive answer or example on other json libraries.

So is it possible?

Comment: "*So is it possible?*" - Java is turing-complete, so yes, it is possible. Look up, for example, jackson. the option in jackson you are looking for is called pretty-printing.

Comment: json-simple library from which source and version? The original project seems stalled.

Comment: Which json library? more information please...